# how to forcefully recenter the cursor even it's on the 1st of the lines in emacs?

Tags: window

)

I wonder if I can forcefully recenter the cursor in emacs.

I often use `C-l` `recenter-top-bottom` command but It couldn't work at the first of the lines. 
I have a vertical monitor for programming purpose, but It's hard to see the top side codes whenever I see.

Is it possible to recenter even the cursor is on the first of the lines?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46823/negative-scrolling-or-actually-recentering-first-line, but there is no offical answer. The answer is "not possible".

Comment: @Heikki Thank you for the answer though :-)